# How to give edit points on pre created shapes or movieclip so users can edit it?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, bezier, curves

I want something like this mentioned in the above link but preferably in AS2 as I dont understand AS3.

Say User uploads a front facing photo. I give co-ordinates . I want to give user facility to move the points to match eyes and lips on  their uploaded photo.

So I want to get the editable shape.

I think we will need to use bezier curves for this.

[How can I modify my code to line through the bezier control points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075544/how-can-i-modify-my-code-to-line-through-the-bezier-control-points)

Comment: like http://www.amway.com/Shop/Product/VirtualMakeover.aspx when we upload image.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.objecthandles.com/ is an Actionscript 3 library.

Comment: I know this library but just cant figure out how it works. I will love to have it in as2

Comment: You may find it helpful to buy a book such as Essential Actionscript.